# Efficiently compute permutations of a given set of "blocks" in a line

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, permutation

I am working on an application where I have a number of blocks which should be positioned on a line. I.e. there are varying number of blocks, each with a different length which should be positioned on the line. There needs to be at least one empty element between blocks.

I would like to get all possible permutations of the blocks on the line efficiently.

For example I have a line of length 15 and would like to place blocks of 1, 6 and 1 size.

Order matters, i.e. in my example the 1-size blocks always should be left and right of the 6-size block.

Possible permutations are

```
X.XXXXXX.X.....
X..XXXXXX.X....
...
.....X.XXXXXX.X
```

How do I efficiently generate all possible permutations in a higher level language, e.g. Java?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this for nonograms?

Comment: yep, I am playing around with building an

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to approach it recursively:

1. If the minimum total length required to store all the blocks with exactly one space in-between them exceeds the available space, there are no ways to place the blocks.
2. Otherwise, if you have no blocks to place, then the only way to place the blocks is to leave all squares unfilled.
3. Otherwise, there are two options.  First, you could place the first block at the first position in the row, then recursively place the remaining blocks in the remaining space within the row after first leaving one extra blank space at the start of the row.  Second, you could leave the first space in the row blank, then recursively place the same set of blocks in the remaining space in the row.  Trying out both options and combining the results back together should give you the answer you're looking for.

Translating this recursive logic into actual Java should not be too difficult.  The code below is designed for readability and can be optimized a bit:

```
public List<String> allBlockOrderings(int rowLength, List<Integer> blockSizes) {
    /* Case 1: Not enough space left. */
    if (spaceNeededFor(blockSizes) > rowLength)) return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    /* Case 2: Nothing to place. */
    if (blockSizes.isEmpty()) {
        result.add(stringOf('.', rowLength));
    } else {
        /* Case 3a: place the very first block at the beginning of the row. */
        List<String> placeFirst = allBlockOrderings(rowLength - blockSizes.get(0) - 1,
                                                    blockSizes.subList(1, blockSizes.length()));
        for (String rest: placeFirst) {
             result.add(stringOf('X', blockSizes.get(0)) + rest);
        }

        /* Case 3b: leave the very first spot open. */
        List<String> skipFirst = allBlockOrderings(rowLength - 1, blockSizes);
        for (String rest: skipFirst) {
             result.add('.' + rest);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

You'll need to implement the `spaceNeededFor` method, which returns the length of the shortest row that could possibly hold a given list of blocks, and the `stringOf` method, which takes in a character and a number, then returns a string of that many copies of the given character.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ShivaKomuravelly- Try thinking about where you're going to place the first block.  It's either at the very first spot, or you leave the first spot open.  If you try both of these options (placing the first block at the start of the row, or leaving a space open at the start of the row), then recursively place all remaining blocks in the unused space, you'll generate all possible placements.  Also, I've added some code if that helps.

Comment: thanks, I'll try to code it similar to this and will report back if it works

Comment: I have now implemented a solution similar to this one, although the number of Permutations naturally grows exponentially for larger lines, so I did not store the Permutations, but rather used a Callback to allow functionality to stop the recursion as soon as a match is found, which allows the permutation to run much faster in almost all practical cases.

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems more easy to think about the problem in another way:

We have fixed blocks in a fixed order, separated by dots. We can create all permutations by distributing the remaining dots over the allowed positions.

The length of this fixed part of the line is:

```
fixed_len = length_of_all_blocks + number_of_blocks - 1
```

The number of remaining dots is

```
free_dots = length_of_line - fixed_len.
```

The number of open positions is

```
pos_count = number_of_blocks + 1
```

Now we have to find all permutations of how to put free_dots into pos_count.

Comment: here `free_dots` doenst include those dots which are in between ... Right??

Comment: @ShivaKomuravelly- This sounds like an excellent solution.  You probably have a bug somewhere in your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to determine what an "efficient implementation" is since the output can be very large and therefore even a fast implementation won't be fast enough.

I'd use technics of dynamic programming and recursion for such task. The recursive fuoction should take two parameters - list of unused numbers and remaining length of the row. Inside it will be a simple loop. You should store the results you already know. I'm sure you can handle the details by yourself. Edit : Our friend has already done that for you :-).

By the way, what is the goal of such task? It remainds me about the pictures in a grid where you have such numbers for every row and column and you need to decode the picture. There are better ways to solve such problem.